# How to organize my content as timeline

Tags: nodes, views

I've started learning Drupal a few months ago and I can say that the community is great and that I haven't had the need to ask a question here until now.

I've started to work on a project and I have a problem with one part.

I need to create something like timeline. There is a requirement for a line where the titles of nodes would be listed according to the date of creating, and I need to list some of the fields of those nodes (like text, image...).

The main problem for me is that I have to show the nodes through views because of some additional filters. I've tried a few available modules and they work great, but the problem with them is that they are vertical, and what I need is a horizontal timeline.

I've tried [A Simple Timeline](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_timeline) and [Ajax Timeline](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_timeline) module.

Is there maybe some other module that I haven't found and that could be useful for what I need?

Off course, It would be great if someone more experienced could give me some idea from which I could start working.

I just want to mention that I'm using the latest Drupal version (7.34) and I installed the latest version of Views module (3.8).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Drupal Answers.

If you want to pay for a module I have recently found a great module that has all the functions you mentioned above. I bought it and I can say that it has amazing settings for timeline and also works through Views.

Take a look at [this page](http://codecanyon.net/item/content-timeline-responsive-drupal-plugin/9871166).

Comment: Thanks, Mixerowsky. I'm checking it right now. Looks great.

Answer (score 1):

I did build a fancy timeline using module 'jQuery timelinr integration', which only is a style for Views letting you render your data as a timeline.

Check the library demo : http://www.csslab.cl/ejemplos/timelinr/latest/horizontal.html

Here the full project : http://www.csslab.cl/2011/08/18/jquery-timelinr/

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://middleagesbrewing.com/about) is another example. This example is using [Views Timeline JS Integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_timelinejs)